# Setting a thumbnail image for Google drive

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I am trying to set a thumbnail image for a Google drive file (containing a reference to an external external application object):

```
data={"thumbnail": {
        "mimeType":"image/png",
        "image":base64.urlsafe_b64encode(image)
        }
    }

headers={
    "Authorization": "Bearer "+accessToken,
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }

rsp=requests.patch("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/"+id,data=json.dumps(data), timeout=15, headers=headers)
```

The requests succeeds (200), but the Drive UI does not display the preview.

When I try to load the thumbnailLink from file resource, a 404 status is reported.

Comment: What happens when you try `"mimeType": "image/*"` ?

Comment: The problem remains the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the thumbnail size. It was too small (100px*70px).

The docs says, that the thumbnail **should** be 220px or bigger.

The correct description should be: The thumbnail **must** be 220px or bigger