# Updating thumbnails on google drive

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-drive-api

I am using the google drive API to update the thumbnails of some files that are stored on Google Drive.

```
GTLRDrive_File *update = [ GTLRDrive_File object ];
update.contentHints = [ GTLRDrive_File_ContentHints object ];
update.contentHints.thumbnail = [ GTLRDrive_File_ContentHints_Thumbnail object ];
update.contentHints.thumbnail.mimeType = @"image/png";
update.contentHints.thumbnail.image = base64UrlEncodedImage;

GTLRDriveQuery_FilesUpdate *query =
[ GTLRDriveQuery_FilesUpdate queryWithObject:update
                                           fileId:metadata.identifier
                                 uploadParameters:NULL ];

query.fields = uploadFileFieldsParam;

[ [ GoogleDriveConnector googleDriveService ] 
executeQuery:query 
completionHandler:^(GTLRServiceTicket *ticket, GTLRDrive_File *updatedMetadata,NSError *error)
```

The query executes properly.  HTTP returns 200 OK.  The fileId and other fields are returned on the response.  But when I see the file on Google Drive, it has an invalid (long) URL for the thumbnail (Using open image on another tab) - https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/GlnPfIj_tU1McaUy9sTyUOzavxIFbj-.....
If I click this URL, it displays the very helpful 404.  The requested URL was not found on this server.  That's all we know.

If I copy the base64UrlEncodedImage URL to the API console and execute the query the thumbnail gets generated fine.  The only difference I can see is that the Session Fetcher is using https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files while the console uses https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/.  Neither of the two URLs does not have an upload prefix in them.

Do I need to pass uploadParameters to the queryWithObject, even though no file is being uploaded, only its thumbnail is.

Any guidance or tips on how to localize/debug this would be helpful.

Comment: Try checking if your image is following the requirements to be uploaded, as stated in this related SO [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21529425/5995040) the requests succeeds (200), but the Drive UI does not display the preview. When OP tried to load the thumbnailLink from file resource, a 404 status is reported. Hope this helps.

Comment: I already tried that.  The image is at 480 px width and height.  I also know that the web safe conversion base64url is proper because it works from the developer console app, if I cut'n'paste and tested it.  Its only something that the ios api client library is doing differently that is causing it not to add the thumbnail.  Also, the thumnailLink gets generated, so it appears the google driver server is failing someplace after generating the link.  But it still gives a 200.